# No Error but page remains blank with passing variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, global-variables, echo

I have a little test project set up so that when you click a wolves's name, it takes them to a page that I want to use to personalize information concerning whichever wolf they clicked on. The page is called wolf.php. I'm trying to using passing variable the $_GET method to assign the URL the wolves id, i.e www.testsite.com/wolf.php?id=1 but the page then displays nothing even though I do not get an error.

Here's the home page (home.php)

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wolves WHERE owner = '$username'");
while($wolf = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<a href= wolf.php?id=$wolf[id]>$wolf[name]</a>";
};
?>
```

Clicking this link takes me to www.testsite.com/wolf.php?id=1 (or whatever the id was). On wolf.php I have this:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT name FROM wolves WHERE id = '$id'") or die("Error: no  
such wolf exists");
echo .$result['name'].
;
?>
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong but this doesn't seem to be working. No information regarding the id of the wolf shows up. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). 
You need to use the appropriate method of your database library
to escape your data prior to making the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in development so you see the fatal syntax errors in your code.  It is also recommended to remove `@` error suppression operator from your `mysql_*()` calls.

You have syntax problems on the last line. Unexpected `.` concatenation operators:

```
// Wrong:
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'
echo .$result['name'].
;

// Should be:
echo $result['name'];
```

Next, you have not fetched a row from your query:

```
// mysql_query() won't error if there are no rows found.  Instead you have to check mysql_num_rows()
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM wolves WHERE id = '$id'") or die("Query error: " . mysql_error());
// Zero rows found, echo error message.
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
  echo "No such wolf.";
}
else {
  // Row found, fetch and display.
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

Note that this script is wide open to SQL injection. At a minimum, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your query input variables.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Ultimately, think about using PDO or MySQLi instead of the old `mysql_*()` functions, as they support prepared statements for greater security over manually escaping variables.  The `mysql_*()` functions are planned for deprecation.

Comment: I fixed the syntax problem but still get a blank page. Thanks for warning regarding SQL injection, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Sunden See above, you had not fetched a row from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly need fetch a result row.

Variant 1 - associative array (values are avialable as field names)

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $result['name'];
```

Variant 2 - enumerated array (by index, started from zero)

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wolves WHERE owner = '$username'");
```

You forgot the `session_start();` at the begining. `$username` is "" and the sql maybe is returning 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet you can't treat `$result` like it's an array; it's a resource identifier. To get an array, do:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'];
```

Also read about SQL injection vulnerability.